# Overloading methods is not supported in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c

I know that Objective-C does not support method overloading. However, how can I understand the following delegate methods with the same name as 'tableView'? To me, those methods seem to be overloading ones, but I am not sure.

For a view controller to indicate that it is a UITableView delegate, it must implement the UITableViewDelegate protocol. The following are common delegate methods to implement in the view controller:

```
tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:
tableView:willDisplayCell:forRowAtIndexPath:
tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:
tableView:didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:
tableView:commitEditingStyle:forRowAtIndexPath:
tableView:canEditRowAtIndexPath:
```

Comment: Those are all different. The entire string, including the ':' and everything following is part of the method/selector name.

Answer (score 7):

All the methods you list are different, because the selector name includes all the parts, not just the part up to the first colon '`:`'.

Here is an example of attempted method overloading in Objective C (which the compiler will reject):

```
- addSomething:(NSObject *) toView:(UIView *)view
- addSomething:(UIView *) toView:(UIView *)view   // won't work
```

Note that you are allowed to 'overload' a method when there is a **class method** and an **instance method** variant with the **same name**:

```
- addSomething:(NSObject *) toView:(UIView *)view 
+ addSomething:(NSObject *) toView:(UIView *)view  // this is OK
```

Obviously you'd want quite a good reason to do something potentially confusing like this!

See also this question:

[Class method and instance method with the same name in Objective-C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13747521/class-method-and-instance-method-with-the-same-name-in-objective-c/13748056)

Comment: Thank me by accepting my answer please. click on the tick to the left of the answer, it should go green.